# jQuery Clone and .change dropdown

Tags: jquery

I'm having a little problem with a jQuery Clone and a .change from a dropdown.

What happens is that I need to update a div with a number from a dropdown and everything is fine, the problem comes when I clone the dropdown and after this the cloned items don't update the number with the selected value and the first one will update all.

```
<button type="button" id="addmore" >Add More</button>
<br>

<div class="dynamic-content1">
    <select name="list" class="list" id="name">
        <option value="25">Ticket 1</option>
        <option value="50">Ticket 2</option>
        <option value="70">Ticket 3</option>
    </select>
    <div class="tag">25</div>
</div>
```

and jQuery:

```
var count = 0;
$('#addmore').click(function(){

    var $clone = $('.dynamic-content1:eq(0)').clone();
    $clone.find('[id]').each(function(){this.id+=''});
    $clone.attr('id', "added"+(++count));
    $('.dynamic-content1:eq(0)').after($clone);

});


$('#name').change(function(event) {
    $('.tag').html($('#name').val());
});
```

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/QuadDamage/ej0t9c0e/

I believe I should run an each statement but honestly I'm not seeing how to do it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code as bellow please.

```
$('#name').change(function(event) {
   $('.tag').html($('#name').val());
});
```

Add this code please

```
$(document).on('change', '.list', function() {
    $(this).parent().next().html($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: works good, do you care to elaborate what is the code why the separated $(document) is doing? Thanks

Comment: Your code was fine until I wrapped it up inside a div, now is broken again. It's something related with the .next I belive -> http://jsfiddle.net/QuadDamage/p843nc9j/

Comment: I replaced the code with `$(this).parent().next().html($(this).val());`

Comment: jQuery **on** function giving the access for inner html contents, So I am using this to write functions for generated select boxes.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't keep selection while making clone of an element. you can try this

```
  .clone(true)
```

This will copy all evens and data in drop down. I hope this will help you for use events.